# How to increase ActiveRecord thread pool size on heroku

Tags: activerecord, heroku, connection-pooling

Normally I would set the pool size as

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: openkitchen_development
  username: rails
  host: localhost
  pool: 10
  password:
```

in database.yml. However heroku replaces the config file. I'm using girl_friday to
do background db work and need to increase the thread pool size.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simply add a `pool` query parameter to the `DATABASE_URL` in your heroku config.  To set the pool size to 15 in your heroku app use something like:

`heroku config -s | awk '/^DATABASE_URL=/{print $0 "?pool=15"}' | xargs heroku config:add`

Comment: I don't understand how that works. The `DATABASE_URL` is a config shared across all your dynos and workers and does not influence the pool size of your Rails processes. Each Heroku DB plan already has a maximum connection limit. I doubt that tweaking the database URL will increase that limit.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't increase the max connection limit for your DB. What it does is tell each process to create it's own pool of that size. So if your DB has a max conn limit of 20 and you have 4 dynos, you could set a pool size of 5. However you'd probably only want 4, since one off processes (scheduler, heroku run, etc) will need a DB connection too.

Comment: Please note that Heroku now discourages the change of `DATABASE_URL`. It left the connection pool configuration to user's code: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/503#issuecomment-15649732

Answer (score 12):

For what it's worth, using the URL params method as described in other answers here is not recommended by Heroku. They reserve the right to reset or change this URL at any time, and long term this behavior will likely be removed for the Rails build behavior, anyway.

Setting additional parameters via an after-initialize application callback is the recommended way to modify the configuration of your heroku-postgresql databases [per this dev center article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections).

In config/initializers/database_connection.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['pool']              = 10
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Heroku now has a nice article on managing pool sizes - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#connection-pool

Answer (score 3):

remvee's answer gets to the heart of what is needed but since his command caused my console to hang I thought I would write up how to do this manually.

```
heroku config
```

Look for the DATABASE_URL key.  For this example lets say it is:

```
DATABASE_URL:            mysql2://something.example.com/stuff?reconnect=true
```

Add "&pool=10" to the end of the URL (use & instead of ? because the url already has a parameter)

```
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=mysql2://something.example.com/stuff?reconnect=true&pool=10
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not very straight forward but you could try creating your own buildpack.

You'll nee to fork:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby

Then modify the following:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/blob/master/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb#L325-387

Just add the pool size you require.

Then you can create a new Heroku app with your custom buildpack:

```
heroku create --stack cedar --buildpack https://github.com/yourgithubusername/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

That should be it!