# Why doesn't Heroku set the database connection pool to max by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku

By default, a basic database on Heroku has a pool of 5, but you can set it higher manually up to 20 (by tweaking its settings via [these instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#connection-pool)). But why would anyone would prefer to set the pool size lower than the max?

People have asked questions like [How to increase ActiveRecord thread pool size on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045302/how-to-increase-activerecord-thread-pool-size-on-heroku), why doesn't Heroku just set the pool to max?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is just a guess.

Perhaps Heroku doesn't want it set to max. To me, it makes sense to reduce resource overall database connections (and therefore resource consumption) by keeping the default connection pool small. Users who need more will easily find the way to increase it.